# Espresso Enginery

Tags: ruby, sinatra

i use framwork Espresso with Enginery generator (Ruby gems). I create new project, and not understand how work this application. I will work with Espresso. Explain me struct Expresso Application, please.
I can run this apllication: rackup config.ru
I can edit controllers, but i not understand depending between ruby scripts in this project.

i run projects, but why this work it? 
config.ru

```
require File.expand_path('../base/boot', __FILE__)
puts App.urlmap
run App
```

in project not /base/boot directory.

Comment: Can you ask something more specific about one piece of Espresso code you are currently stuck with?

Comment: http://www.fileshare.ro/e29436630 - application created with Enginery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `config.ru` file looks quite normal for a `rack` start-up file. You would start the application from the project folder, with a command like:

```
rackup -p 8080
```

The following line:

```
require File.expand_path('../base/boot', __FILE__)
```

will load in the `../base/boot` file (similar to require_relative, but also works with older Ruby e.g. 1.8.7), which I would guess requires the dependencies where `App` is defined. The class or module `App` will implement a `call` method. To start the server, the rack host calls `App.new` (which is called due to `run App`) and then on each request it will call `.call( env )` on the resulting object (the object doesn't have to be an `App` object, but in simpler frameworks it will be).

The variable `env` contains all the details of the request and the rack environment that can be inspected to fetch details of the current path, cookies, query params etc. Typically access to this data is abstracted through Sinatra and Espresso helper methods that you will use.

The Sinatra and Espresso helper methods look like they are doing magic declarations, but they are just normal methods. Usually they do some calculation and then stash a code block/lambda for rack to call later. Sinatra's `get` is like this . . . it isn't true declarative code. Instead, when the controller is parsed, it just takes the code block and tells the application object to call it (later) when the path matches.

Answer (score 1):

requiring '../base/boot' will actually load dependencies, controllers, models etc. and build the application.

The application are stored under `App` constant, so you can access it from different files:
https://github.com/espresso/enginery/blob/master/app/base/base/boot.rb#L9

`puts App.urlmap` will display all the routes to be served by app.

And `run App` will start your app.

You can also start app by `ruby app.rb`, then you do not need to pass server/port at startup.
Instead you'll set them in `config/config.yml`, like this:

```
development:
  server: Thin
  port:   5252
```

Comment: на здоровье :) ждём новых вопросов, предпочтительно тут-же :)